# Problems with reserved field name 'user' in SAS Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

How do I select the `user` column from my table and not select the surprise 'feature' SAS added to their SQL syntax:

```
data have;
 user = 'huh??';
run;

proc sql ;
  select user from have;
quit;
```

Result:

```
rob
```

Bonus, the field name in the result table (if you create one) gets a temporary name... ie. something like `_TEM001`.

Comment: Just a note that 'User' is a reserved word in SQL https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p0corah7t43hy7n1r7efplde5c8z.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p04jn50swt5cd5n1if75ic2nfi2t (just under first section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the name literal syntax, `'<name>'n`

```
select 'user'n from have;
```

Name literals in other systems, such as in pass through:

- Oracle - double quoted.   `"user"`
- SQL Server - square bracketed `[user]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use column literals to refer specifically to the field name rather than the reserved keyword:

```
proc sql ;
  select 'user'n from have;
quit;
```

Result:

```
huh??
```

Comment: It says double quotes (without n) should work as well?

Comment: Only if "PROC SQL option DQUOTE=ANSI" is in effect.